# How remove indention in theorem environment?

Tags: indentation, theorems, thmtools

How is it possible to remove the indention at the beginning of the theorem text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=L]{boxtheorem L}

\begin{document}
\begin{boxtheorem L}[Euclid]
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p'>p$.
In particular, there are infinitely many primes.
\end{boxtheorem L}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is slightly curious behaviour from the package that you don't notice in many situations.  The space is caused by the line break after `[Euclid]`.  Placing a percent sign directly after `[Euclid]` hides the newline and removes that space.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=L]{boxtheorem L}

\begin{document}
\begin{boxtheorem L}[Euclid]%
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p'>p$.
In particular, there are infinitely many primes.
\end{boxtheorem L}
\end{document}
```

The documentation of `thmtools` is careful to use percent signs at other places in the documentation, but not in the examples related to the `thmbox` option.

Comment: In both the question and the answer, `$p’>p$` should be `$p'>p$` so the prime shows up.

Comment: @Swann: Thanks, sometimes the answer is so simple... ;)

Comment: @EthanBolker Well spotted.  I have now corrected this.

Answer (score 8):

This is due to bad interactions between the packages `thmtools` and `thmbox`, I believe. A way to solve this particular situation seems to be patching an internal command of `thmtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmt@parsetheoremargs
  {\let\@parsecmd\@empty}
  {\let\@parsecmd\ignorespaces}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[thmbox=L]{boxtheorem L}

\begin{document}
\begin{boxtheorem L}[Euclid]
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p'>p$.
In particular, there are infinitely many primes.
\end{boxtheorem L}
\end{document}
```

[image]